# double exclamation on a return value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking over a book for html 5 and it includes this tid bit of js.  What does double exclamation mean?

```
return ! ! document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
```

Comment: Got to love it, double negatives useful in programing languages.  And my english teacher said never use double negative.  "I do not want to do nothing." becomes a sentence that perhaps makes sense now. :)

Comment: I may be an ideaa to first try searching stackoverflow before asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: sorry about that. i did a search under "double exclamation points javascript" Didn't pull up anything.

Answer (score 23):

The `!` operator negates, and the secondary `!` negates the result of the inital negation. This basically typecasts whatever is on the right hand side into a boolean ( true or false ).

```
!false // true
!!false // false
```

So if the method is defined then the `function` which is truthy, will be typecasted into `true`.

```
document.createElement('video').canPlayType
```

So the above returns a function. We don't want a function, we want an explicit boolean, so we negative it twice and since `function` is not falsy ( 0, null, false, empty string, NaN ) then it returns true for browsers which support this method.

```
!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType // true
```

If the method is not supported, the browser will return `undefined`. `!undefined` is true, and `!true` is false, so `!!document.createElement('video').LOL` will return `false`

Comment: wouldn't `document.createElement('video').canPlayType` return a boolean? Or is it for if that is `null` then `!!(null) = false`?

Comment: @hunter - document.createElement('video').canPlayType will return undefined if the browser doesn't support the video tag.

Comment: ... javascript is dumb ... `!null` should throw an exception... dangit

Answer (score 9):

The double exclamation is a JavaScript trick to return true/false regardless of input. In your example, if a browser does not support the video tag, it will return undefined. !undefined is true. So !!undefined is false. If the browser does support video, it will return true. !!true is also true. This saves you from having to handle the case of undefined.